# Fibonacci wrong output? (C)

Tags: c, algorithm, fibonacci

```
int * fibonacci(int n) {
    int range = n + 1;
    int * arr = malloc(range * sizeof(int));
    arr(0) = 0;
    arr(1) = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i < range; ++i) {
        arr(i) = arr(0) + arr(1);   
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I can't seem to pinpoint what's wrong with my program, the output keeps coming out as 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 and so on?

Comment: You should use square brackets, e.g., `arr[0]` or `arr[i]`

Answer (score 5):

```
arr(i) = arr(0) + arr(1);
```

shouldn't that be

```
arr(i) = arr(i-1) + arr(i-2);
```

?

Answer (score 5):

What your code does is the following:

```
arr(3) = 0 + 1
arr(4) = 0 + 1
arr(5) = 0 + 1
```

etc.  You are assigning the same value over and over.

You need to do:

```
 arr(i) = arr(i - 1) + arr(i - 2);
```

**Explanation:**

Say you have the array:

- arr(1) = 0
- arr(2) = 1

and `i` is at index 3, this would assign `arr(3) = arr(2) + arr(1)` which is 1 + 0.  Therefore arr(3) = 1

`i` is now at index 4, this would assign `arr(4) = arr(3) + arr(2)` which is 1 + 1.  Therefore arr(4) = 2